# Is there a way to adjust the width of the columns of beamer's table automatically to their content?

Tags: tables, beamer

As mentioned in the title, I would like to create a nice and simple table of three column and about 14 rows. If all could not fit in one frame. It would be OK to use 2 frames. The first column should content 1 picture for each row. The second column should content only some text of about 10 to 15 characters and the third ones only digit - 2 maximum. That's why I don't want the 2nd and 3rd column take too much space for no reason.
Here's a sketch:

[image]

I tried the following ones after the help of Zarko but now I want put 2 of this table in 1 frame.
I really like this ones

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}

\setbeamercolor{mycolor}{fg=black,bg=blue!30}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\newsavebox\mytable
\newlength{\mytablelength}
\begin{document}
        \begin{frame} 
    \sbox\mytable{\begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.3\textwidth} |c| c| @{}}
    \hline
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=M]{example-image-a}
            & longer text &   some text \\ \hline
              \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=M]{example-image-a}
            & longer text &   some text \\ \hline
                      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=M]{example-image-a}
            & longer text &   some text \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
                }
    \settowidth{\mytablelength}{\usebox\mytable}
    \hfil%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\mytablelength,sep=1ex,rounded=true,shadow]{mycolor}
        \centering
    \usebox\mytable
        \end{beamercolorbox}
    \end{frame}
   \end{document}
```

### The header is not mandatory.

First of thank. I just try to change the width of the second column but, it moves the vertical and horizontal lines that separate the rows and columns. 
(Putting it here just because the indentation of the was not working well with the add comment method)

```
\begin{tabular}{p{0.45\textwidth}|p{0.25\textwidth}}
    \textcolor{white}{\bf Head 1} & \textcolor{white}{\bf Head 2} \\
    \includegraphics[scale=.1]{Images.png} & \begin{itemize}\item 4\end{itemize}\\ \hline
    \begin{itemize}\item 5\end{itemize} & \begin{itemize}\item 6\end{itemize} \\ \hline
    \begin{itemize}\item \includegraphics[scale=.15]{Im.png}\end{itemize} 
        & \begin{itemize}\item 8\end{itemize} \\ 
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: It is always better to post a complete example people can compile as it makes it easier to help.

Comment: There isn't room for 2, is there? That would be 8 rows total as you have 3 in each table + headers, presumably. At least, your sketch has headers.

Comment: I think I am going to stick with one table per frame. And I like it. However, I am still receiving the error messages but that's OK since the result feeds my need. Thank you all for your time.

Comment: You ignore error messages at your peril. If they are warnings, that's one thing. But actual errors mean trouble and should not be ignored.

Comment: Differently from forums, here we don't add "solved" to the title.

Comment: @egreg Sorry, I didn't know that. Thanks for having remove it.

Answer (score 2):

your question is not clear so all in further is based on guessing what you mean with "appropriate start point" ...

As starting point for tweaking your table (adding vertical line, size of picture, colors, ect) can serve the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}

\setbeamercolor{mycolor}{fg=black,bg=blue!30}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\newsavebox\mytable
\newlength{\mytablelength}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame} 
\sbox\mytable{\begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.3\textwidth} c c @{}}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=M]{example-image-a}
        & some longer text &   some text \\
\end{tabular}
            }
\settowidth{\mytablelength}{\usebox\mytable}

\hfil%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\mytablelength,sep=1ex,rounded=true,shadow]{mycolor}
    \centering
\usebox\mytable
    \end{beamercolorbox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

In above MWE the width of `beamercolorbox` is adopted to table width. For the are added all complications with save box, defining new length and set width to measured with of table.

Image width is determined with width of the first column, i.e.: `p{0.3\textwidth}`. If you like to change width of picture, you only need to change this column width. Picture is vertical centered  in table row (consequently also text in other two columns looks as vertical centered. with change `valingn` option (provided with package `adjustbox`) to T or delete it you can change position to top or baseline aligned respectively.

**Addendum:**
After editing of question some thing are more clear ... so it seems that you looking for something like this:

[image]

For this is employed `tcolorbox` package. MWE (complex version):

```
\RequirePackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
    \usepackage{array,makecell,tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\large\bfseries\color{blue!70!black}}

\newsavebox\mytable
\newlength{\mytablelength}

\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\sbox\mytable{\begin{tabular}{|p{0.15\textwidth} | c | c |}
                                \hline
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, margin=3pt]{example-image-a}
            & \thead{name}   &   \thead{number:} \\
              \end{tabular}
            }
\settowidth{\mytablelength}{\usebox\mytable}

\tcbset{enhanced,
        width=\mytablelength,
        fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries, fontupper=\small\sffamily,
        colback=blue!5, colframe=blue!50!black,
        }% end \tcbset
\centering

\begin{tcolorbox}[tabularx={@{} X | c | c }]
\thead{Figure}  
        &   \thead{name}        &   \thead{number}  \\      \hline
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=M, margin=3pt]{example-image-a}
        & image 1\phantom{4}    &   1   \\      \hline
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=M, margin=3pt]{example-image-b}
        & image 2   &   3   \\      \hline
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=M, margin=3pt]{example-image-c}
        & image 3   &   3   \\      \hline
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=M, margin=3pt]{example-image-a}
        & image 4   &   4   \\      \hline
   \end{tcolorbox}

\framebreak
\begin{tcolorbox}[tabularx={@{} X | c | c }]
\thead{Figure}
        &   \thead{name}        &   \thead{number}  \\      \hline
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=M, margin=3pt]{example-image-a}
        & image 5\phantom{4}    &   5  \\      \hline
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=M, margin=3pt]{example-image-b}
        & image 6  &   6    \\      \hline
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=M, margin=3pt]{example-image-c}
        & image 7  &   7    \\      \hline
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=M, margin=3pt]{example-image-a}
        & image 8  &   8    \\      \hline
   \end{tcolorbox}


\framebreak
\begin{tcolorbox}[tabularx={@{} X | c | c }]
\thead{Figure}
        &   \thead{name}        &   \thead{number}  \\      \hline
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=M, margin=3pt]{example-image-a}
        & image 9   &   9   \\      \hline
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=M, margin=3pt]{example-image-b}
        & image 10  &   10  \\      \hline
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=M, margin=3pt]{example-image-c}
        & image 11  &   11  \\      \hline
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=M, margin=3pt]{example-image-a}
        & image 12  &   12  \\      \hline
   \end{tcolorbox}

\framebreak
\begin{tcolorbox}[tabularx={@{} X | c | c }]
\thead{Figure}
        &   \thead{name}        &   \thead{number}  \\      \hline
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=M, margin=3pt]{example-image-a}
        & image 13  &   13  \\      \hline
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=M, margin=3pt]{example-image-b}
        & image 14  &   14  \\      \hline
   \end{tcolorbox}
\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \end{document}
```

Considering, than on one slide can be placed only four rows, you can define line width as 57mm and simplified code to MWE (simpler version):

```
\RequirePackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
    \usepackage{array,makecell,tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\large\bfseries\color{blue!70!black}}

\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]

\tcbset{enhanced,
        width=57mm,
        fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries, fontupper=\small\sffamily,
        colback=blue!5, colframe=blue!50!black,
        }% end \tcbset
\centering

... further as in MWE above ...
```

**Addendum (2):**
Improved  version of suggestion in the first addendum. For purpose of distinguishes from it I select different colors for table, which can be easy to change of desired one.

Main differences:

- defined dedicated `tcolorbox` for tables with colored first table row and added fuzzy shadow (for more fancy looks)
- all columns widths have determined width with measurement the most length cell in column (for this purpose are defined two now length and new column type `C` for centering of second and third columns)
- for placement of figures in table is (as before, but slightly different) employed `adjustbox` package. By it helps is defined top and bottom margin around image as well position regarding baseline in row (in the first part of table is demonstrated possible positions: in the first two row is vertical centered by option `M` and `m` respectively, in the third row is top aligned by option `t` and in the third part bottom aligned /o option, default feature/, other two parts use option `M`).

Obtained first part of table is:

[image]

MWE:

```
\RequirePackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array,makecell,tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\color{white}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\newsavebox\mytable
\newlength{\mytablelength}
\newlength{\secondcol}
\newlength{\thirdcol}

\newtcolorbox{tctabularx}[1]{%
        enhanced,
        width=\mytablelength,
        arc=0mm,
        colback=yellow!20!white, colframe=orange!80!white,
        drop fuzzy shadow,
        #1,
        before upper app={\hline\rowcolor{orange!80!white}}
                            }% end tctabularx

\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\settowidth\secondcol{\thead{image 14}}           % <-- the longest cell in second column   
\settowidth\thirdcol{\thead{number}}
\settowidth{\mytablelength}{\usebox\mytable}
\sbox\mytable{\begin{tabular}{| p{0.145\textwidth}% <-- define width of figures 
                              | p{\secondcol} |  p{\thirdcol} |}
                a   &   b   &   c                 % <-- dummy table content
              \end{tabular}
             }
\settowidth{\mytablelength}{\usebox\mytable}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \centering
\begin{tctabularx}{tabularx={ X | C{\secondcol} | C{\thirdcol} |} }
\thead{Figure}
        &   \thead{name}        &   \thead{number}  \\      \hline
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=M, margin=0pt 2pt]{example-image-a}
        & image 1   &   1   \\      \hline
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=m, margin=0pt 2pt]{example-image-b}
        & image 2   &   3   \\      \hline
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t, margin=0pt 2pt]{example-image-c}
        & image 3   &   3   \\      \hline
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,margin=0pt 2pt]{example-image-a}
        & image 4   &   4   \\      \hline
   \end{tctabularx}

\framebreak
\begin{tctabularx}{tabularx={ X | C{\secondcol} | C{\thirdcol} |} }
\thead{Figure}
        &   \thead{name}        &   \thead{number}  \\      \hline
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=M, margin=0pt 2pt]{example-image-a}
        & image 5   &   5  \\      \hline
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=M, margin=0pt 2pt]{example-image-b}
        & image 6   &   6    \\      \hline
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=M, margin=0pt 2pt]{example-image-c}
        & image 7   &   7    \\      \hline
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=M, margin=0pt 2pt]{example-image-a}
        & image 8   &   8    \\      \hline
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=M, margin=0pt 2pt]{example-image-a}
        & image 9   &   9   \\      \hline
   \end{tctabularx}

\framebreak
\begin{tctabularx}{tabularx={ X | C{\secondcol} | C{\thirdcol} |} }
\thead{Figure}
        &   \thead{name}        &   \thead{number}  \\      \hline
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=M, margin=0pt 2pt]{example-image-b}
        & image 10  &   10  \\      \hline
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=M, margin=0pt 2pt]{example-image-c}
        & image 11  &   11  \\      \hline
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=M, margin=0pt 2pt]{example-image-a}
        & image 12  &   12  \\      \hline
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=M, margin=0pt 2pt]{example-image-a}
        & image 13  &   13  \\      \hline
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=M, margin=0pt 2pt]{example-image-b}
        & image 14  &   14  \\      \hline
   \end{tctabularx}
\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \end{document}
```

Comment: First of thank. I just try to change the width of the second column but, it moves the vertical and horizontal lines that separate the rows and columns.               
<code>\begin{tabular}{p{0.45\textwidth}|p{0.25\textwidth}}
\textcolor{white}{\bf Head 1} & \textcolor{white}{\bf Head 2} \\
\includegraphics[scale=.1]{Images.png} &
\begin{itemize}\item 4\end{itemize}\\ \hline
\begin{itemize}\item 5\end{itemize} &
\begin{itemize}\item 6\end{itemize} \\ \hline
\begin{itemize}\item \includegraphics[scale=.15]{Im.png}\end{itemize} & \begin{itemize}\item 8\end{itemize} \\
\end{tabular}<code>

Comment: Also, just try adding the 3rd column but it didn't work. Actually, in my 3rd column will only have 2 digits maximum. the second around 10 characters and the first one a picture.

Comment: Where you added? To MWE in the my answer? Please,  edit your question: add code in your comment, show its result and describe, what is going wrong. By the way, in your table you not consider my suggestion ...

Comment: <pre>\begin{frame} 
\sbox\mytable{\begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.3\textwidth} |c| c| @{}}
\hline
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=M]{example-image-a}
& longer text &   some text \\ \hline
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=M]{example-image-a}
& longer text &   some text \\ \hline
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=M]{example-image-a}
& longer text &   some text \\ \hline
\end{tabular} }
\settowidth{\mytablelength}{\usebox\mytable}
\hfil%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\mytablelength,sep=1ex,rounded=true,shadow]{mycolor}
\centering
\usebox\mytable 
\end{...} <code>

Comment: This is working, but how could we make the picture float in the centre of the first column? And yeah, I want a table of several lines. I added some horizontal and vertical lines. Also, how could I put 2 of this table in one beamer frame? Trying to add the scale before the "width option in the square bracket right after \includegraphics. p.s. I apologise because I have trouble of using the indent for the code in the comment section

Comment: The image width is equal to column width! there is nothing to center! More rows aren't any problem. I encourage you again to edit your question and clarify what is your problem. with some sketch try to illustrate it. This will be visible to more people and maybe someone will better understand you than me.

Comment: Also, I am getting several of this error message even though, the result is here. Would like to know how to fix them but at after getting the desired result since they are not preventing the correct displaying of the table.

Comment: Just edit the question. Hope it is clear than before. Also, I added one sketch. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Nelson Please don't add code in comments. Edit your question where you can format it readably!

Comment: @Zarko, Thanks for the new table, even nicer.